# Extract the positions of their maximum pixel value of an image

Tags: python, image-processing

I am a newbie here. I am trying to get a single line of the edge of the 2D flame then I can calculate the actual area - 3D flame area. The first thing is getting the edge. The 2D flame is sort of side-viewed concave flame, so the flame base (flat part) is brighter than the concave segment. I use the code below the find the edge, my method is finding the maximum pixel value follow the y-axis. The result seems not to get my purpose, could you please help me figure out? Thanks very much in advance.
[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnjmM.jpg) In the code I rotate the image

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

def initialization_rotate(path):
    global h,w,img
    img4 = np.array(Image.open(path).convert('L'))
    img3 = img4.transpose(1,0)
    img2 = img3[::-1,::1]
    img = img2[400:1000,1:248]
    h, w = img.shape

path = 'D:\\20190520\\14\\14\\1767.jpg'

#Noise cancellation
def opening(binary):
    opened = np.zeros_like(binary)              
    for j in range(1,w-1):
        for i in range(1,h-1):
            if binary[i][j]> 100:
                n1 = binary[i-1][j-1]
                n2 = binary[i-1][j]
                n3 = binary[i-1][j+1]
                n4 = binary[i][j-1]
                n5 = binary[i][j+1]
                n6 = binary[i+1][j-1]
                n7 = binary[i+1][j]
                n8 = binary[i+1][j+1]
                sum8 = int(n1) + int(n2) + int(n3) + int(n4) + int(n5) + int(n6) + int(n7) + int(n8)
                if sum8 < 1000:
                    opened[i][j] = 0
                else:
                    opened[i][j] = 255
            else:
                pass
    return opened    


edge = np.zeros_like(img)


# Find the max pixel value and extract the postion
for j in range(w-1):
    ys = [0]
    ymax = []
    for i in range(h-1):
         if img[i][j] > 100:
            ys.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    ymax = np.amax(ys)
    edge[ymax][j] = 255


cv2.namedWindow('edge')

while(True):
    cv2.imshow('edge',edge)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do you want to get the single brightest pixel of the 2D array or you want to do edge detection of the spot that is over the background noise?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
By getting all spots which have the brightest pixel in each column following y-axis, I can gather them all to form the edge of the flame. My bad for poor description.

Comment: Are you after the left or right edge ?

Comment: Will you please provide a url for a jpeg file for me to do edge detection? 2D flat matrix like preferably.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your comment, the photo is an instant moment of a downward-propagating flame in a tube. The flame propagates from top to bottom as from the right to left in the image.

Comment: @Amit Could you find the image following the link: https://imgur.com/gFYOOV3. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I will let you know soon

Comment: @GiaTri: you do not answer my question.

Comment: I wrote the detection algorithm from scratch and I am not sure if similarities exist elsewhere. However, I have had very limited success so far and that too with simple images. With the image that you gave I am finding it very hard to do edge detection reliably. I am not sure if you would be interested in it.

Comment: @Amit Very appreciate your kindly effort. As I said, I am a newbie, so it better than not thing, so could you send me the code. At least I can learn from a different angle that maybe lead to a new idea. Moreover, I made a new code, I would like to check with your also.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see, It would be nice if you can tell me more specific about your question. Thanks alot

Comment: @GiaTri I have added my "answer" .. not sure how helpful it will be

Comment: There are some very talented people trying to help you, but it is unclear what you actually want as an answer. Please add **another** image showing clearly in red or similar what you want to locate. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Could you check the image for more clear about my answer. I try to create the single edge line as a boundary of the flame in the image. My idea is finding the maximum pixel value in each horizontal axis (in my code I rotate the image so it turns out max pixel value in each vertical axis).
https://imgur.com/3bq4BuT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a very quick coding and from ground up (without looking into established or state of art algorithms on edge detection). Not very suprisingly, the results are very poor. The code that I have pasted below will work only for RGB (i.e. only for three channels and not for images that are CMYK, grey-scale or RGBA or anything else). Also I have tested on single very simplistic image. In real life the images are complicated. I don't think it will fair very well there, yet. It needs a lot of work. However I am, hesitatingly, sharing it since it was requested by @Gia Tri.

Here is what I did. For every column I calculated the mean intensities and stddev intensities. I hoped that at the edge there will be change in the intensities from the average +- stdev (multiplied by a factor). If I mark the first and last in the column, I will have edge for every column and hopfully, once I stitch it, it will form and edge. The code and the attached image is for you to see, how I fared.

```py
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

UppperStdBoundaryMultiplier = 1.0
LowerStdBoundaryMultiplier = 1.0
NegativeSelection = False

def SumSquareRGBintensityOfPixel(Pixel):
    return np.sum(np.power(Pixel,2),axis=0)

def GetTheContinousStretchForAcolumn(Column):
    global UppperStdBoundaryMultiplier
    global LowerStdBoundaryMultiplier
    global NegativeSelection
    SumSquaresIntensityOfColumn = np.apply_along_axis(SumSquareRGBintensityOfPixel,1,Column)
    Mean = np.mean(SumSquaresIntensityOfColumn)
    StdDev = np.std(SumSquaresIntensityOfColumn)
    LowerThreshold = Mean - LowerStdBoundaryMultiplier*StdDev
    UpperThreshold = Mean + UppperStdBoundaryMultiplier*StdDev
    if NegativeSelection:
        Index = np.where(SumSquaresIntensityOfColumn < LowerThreshold)
        Column[Index,:] = np.array([255,255,255])
    else:
        Index = np.where(SumSquaresIntensityOfColumn >= LowerThreshold)
        LeastIndex = Index[Index==True][0]
        LastIndex = Index[Index==True][-1]
        Column[[LeastIndex,LastIndex],:] =  np.array([255,0,0])
    return Column

def DoEdgeDetection(ImageFilePath):
    FileHandle = ndimage.imread(ImageFilePath)
    for Column in range(FileHandle.shape[1]):
        FileHandle[:,Column,:] = GetTheContinousStretchForAcolumn(FileHandle[:,Column,:])
    plt.imshow(FileHandle)
    plt.show()

DoEdgeDetection("/PathToImage/Image_1.jpg")
```

And below is the result. To the left is the query image whose edge had to be detected and to the right is the edge detected image. Edge points are marked in red dots. As you can see it fared poorly but with some investment of time and thinking, it might do far better ... or may be not. May be it is a good start but far from finish .. You, please, be the judge!

[image: May be a good start but far from finish]

***** Edit after clarification on requirement from GiaTri ***************

So I did manage to change the program, the idea remained same. However this time the problem is overly simplified to the case that you want to detect only blue flame. Actually I went ahead and made it functional for all three color channels. However I doubt, it will be useful to you beyond blue channel.

**How to use the program below **

If your flame is vertical then choose edges = "horizontal" in the class asignment. If your edges are horizontal then choose edges = "vertical". This might be a little confusing but for the time being please use it. Later either you can change it or I can change it.

So first let me convince you that the edge detection is working much better than yesterday. See the two images below. I have taken these two flame images from internet. As before the image whose edge has to be detected is on the left and on the right is the edge-detected image. The edges are in red dot.

First [horizontal flame](https://images.app.goo.gl/4a4JiTwtH66zpT9T8).

[image: Horizontal flame detected]

and then [a vertical flame](https://images.app.goo.gl/xVYYibrjTKHmPQFo7).

[image: Vertical flame detected].

**There is still a lot of work left in this.** However if you are a little more convinced than yesterday, then below is the code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread

class DetectEdges():

    def __init__(self, ImagePath, Channel = ["blue"], edges="vertical"):
        self.Channel = Channel
        self.edges = edges
        self.Image_ = imread(ImagePath)
        self.Image = np.copy(self.Image_)
        self.Dimensions_X, self.Dimensions_Y, self.Channels = self.Image.shape
        self.BackGroundSamplingPercentage = 0.5

    def ShowTheImage(self):
        plt.imshow(self.Image)
        plt.show()

    def GetTheBackGroundPixels(self):
        NumberOfPoints = int(self.BackGroundSamplingPercentage*min(self.Dimensions_X, self.Dimensions_Y))
        Random_X = np.random.choice(self.Dimensions_X, size=NumberOfPoints, replace=False)
        Random_Y = np.random.choice(self.Dimensions_Y, size=NumberOfPoints, replace=False)
        Random_Pixels = np.array(list(zip(Random_X,Random_Y)))
        return Random_Pixels

    def GetTheChannelEdge(self):
        BackGroundPixels = self.GetTheBackGroundPixels()
        if self.edges == "vertical":
            if self.Channel == ["blue"]:
                MeanBackGroundInensity = np.mean(self.Image[BackGroundPixels[:,0],BackGroundPixels[:,1],2])
                for column in range(self.Dimensions_Y):
                    PixelsAboveBackGround = np.where(self.Image[:,column,2]>MeanBackGroundInensity)
                    if PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True].shape[0] > 0:
                        TopPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][0]
                        BottomPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][-1]
                        self.Image[[TopPixel,BottomPixel],column,:] = [255,0,0]
            if self.Channel == ["red"]:
                MeanBackGroundInensity = np.mean(self.Image[BackGroundPixels[:,0],BackGroundPixels[:,1],0])
                for column in range(self.Dimensions_Y):
                    PixelsAboveBackGround = np.where(self.Image[:,column,0]>MeanBackGroundInensity)
                    if PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True].shape[0] > 0:
                        TopPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][0]
                        BottomPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][-1]
                        self.Image[[TopPixel,BottomPixel],column,:] = [0,255,0]
            if self.Channel == ["green"]:
                MeanBackGroundInensity = np.mean(self.Image[BackGroundPixels[:,0],BackGroundPixels[:,1],1])
                for column in range(self.Dimensions_Y):
                    PixelsAboveBackGround = np.where(self.Image[:,column,1]>MeanBackGroundInensity)
                    if PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True].shape[0] > 0:
                        TopPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][0]
                        BottomPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][-1]
                        self.Image[[TopPixel,BottomPixel],column,:] = [255,0,0]
        elif self.edges=="horizontal":
            if self.Channel == ["blue"]:
                MeanBackGroundInensity = np.mean(self.Image[BackGroundPixels[:,0],BackGroundPixels[:,1],2])
                for row in range(self.Dimensions_X):
                    PixelsAboveBackGround = np.where(self.Image[row,:,2]>MeanBackGroundInensity)
                    if PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True].shape[0] > 0:
                        LeftPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][0]
                        RightPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][-1]
                        self.Image[row,[LeftPixel,RightPixel],:] = [255,0,0]
            if self.Channel == ["red"]:
                MeanBackGroundInensity = np.mean(self.Image[BackGroundPixels[:,0],BackGroundPixels[:,1],0])
                for row in range(self.Dimensions_X):
                    PixelsAboveBackGround = np.where(self.Image[row,:,0]>MeanBackGroundInensity)
                    if PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True].shape[0] > 0:
                        LeftPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][0]
                        RightPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][-1]
                        self.Image[row,[LeftPixel,RightPixel],:] = [0,255,0]
            if self.Channel == ["green"]:
                MeanBackGroundInensity = np.mean(self.Image[BackGroundPixels[:,0],BackGroundPixels[:,1],1])
                for row in range(self.Dimensions_X):
                    PixelsAboveBackGround = np.where(self.Image[row,:,1]>MeanBackGroundInensity)
                    if PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True].shape[0] > 0:
                        LeftPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][0]
                        RightPixel = PixelsAboveBackGround[PixelsAboveBackGround==True][-1]
                        self.Image[row,[LeftPixel,RightPixel],:] = [255,0,0]



Test = DetectEdges("FlameImagePath",Channel = ["blue"],edges="vertical")
Test.GetTheChannelEdge()
Test.ShowTheImage()
```

Please let me know if this was of any "more" help or I missed some salient requirements.

Best wishes,

Comment: Thank you very much, Amit. It's actually not really work in my image because my image is just considered a sort of blue image, not completely RGB one. Now I have no comment about it but I am learning your code about the idea of calculating the mean intensity in each column. As you said it needs more effort to perfectly match my image and I am still working on it. Thanks again.

Comment: How about changing the method to find the peak intensity of each column pixel instead using the mean intensity?

Comment: Yes it can be done. Please wait for few hours. As soon as I am near my computer, I will try to make changes. Thank you.

Comment: That's so great. 
Because using the mean intensity, I afraid that the curve section of flame (I mean cellular part) won't be detected correctly, the lower part, I mean the flame base which has higher intensity (please refer the link:https://imgur.com/3bq4BuT). So with the idea of peak intensity, I think the code can eliminate the below part of the curve (cell shape).

Comment: @GiaTri  Situation is improved than yesterday. See the post above. Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help. 

The code seems not to work for my image, please see the link: https://imgur.com/vyrYk3f.

Comment: I am on mobile but I see some faint red dots. Did you try with a little bigger and/or brighter flame?

Comment: I did, the result is the same. By the way, I will study from your code then apply to my image. Maybe my image is not bright enough compared to the image you took from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

By the way,  Amit, I would like to show my code using the idea of the thresholding pixel value. I would love to discuss with you.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'D:\\20181229__\\7\\Area 7\\1767.jpg'
    img1 = cv2.imread(path)
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img1)
    img3 = b[94:223, 600:700]
    img4 = cv2.flip(img3, 1)
    h,w = img3.shape
    data = []
    th_val = 20
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            val = img3[i, -j]
            if (val >= th_val):
                data.append(j)
                break

    x = range(len(data))
    plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(img4)
    plt.plot(data, x)
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.plot(data, x)
```

please see the link for the result. The thing is the method still not fit totally my desire. I hope a discussion with you.
Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc0Qj.jpg

Comment: Very nice. Congrats for making dent into the problem. I was wondering what is the rationale for doing "img3 = b[94:223, 600:700]"? I mean where did the numbers in the index come from?

Comment: It's actually the scale around the flame in the image. The image is just a frame in the propagation of flame moving down in a tube, so I need to limit the range for the code doing its job in order to save time. I have around 300 images. 94:223 is close to the vertical length of flame as showed in the link above.

But I want to see the result with the idea of finding the peak intensity in each row (following the position of flame in the link). My code my be not the correct one for actual flame edge, I think.

Comment: I see your logic but this means you have an idea of edges before you code and you will also have to change everytime. I also notice that you have restricted yourself to blue channel. It is smart idea but not generic. However if all you need to do is to detect blue edge then it is smart. This also means the problem is a little easier to solve. Please let me think over it. I will try to post a better code or may be edit my post by adding a new code but only in few hours from now.

Comment: Actually, the flame in the image is a kind of hydrocarbon flame, so it a blue flame in general. I know it is greed but if it is fine, could you provide also the function for processing all the images in a folder? Thank you so much.

Comment: I made some progress on the problem. Tomorrow, I will try to dent it more. For the time being you can see the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a dedicated work from you. Extremely appreciate.

The code seems don't work for my image, could you see that in the link: https://imgur.com/vyrYk3f. Cuz my image is horizontal orientation, so I choose vertical in the class assignment.

Do you think my image needs to be set a threshold value for the intensity?

Comment: Please try with an image where the flame is little bigger or brighter. I see some faint red dots around the edge. However I am on mobile. I might be seeing it wrong.